# Can I point a local browser to a file through a remote desktop connection?

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, internet-explorer

I'm not sure if there is a good solution to this problem or not...

We have a database application setup at a client's location that we monitor remotely. We use a remote desktop connection to our server at that location from our office about 100 miles away. The front end to our application is in flash, and we need to watch this stuff constantly. Currently, we open an IE window in the remote desktop and launch our app. The problem is that the flash rendering comes across the line very slowly. It is painful to do simple tasks.

It would be much faster if we could run flash/IE locally, and just point it at the server in the remote location. Is this possible using the remote desktop connection we already have?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No.

You can't point a local browser at a file on another machine without the other machine serving the file. You could however remote desktop in, start an Apache web server, and then browser files if you had a routed ip address for the remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered an alternate solution, like a VPN or SSH tunnel?

Comment: We used to have VPN. But I think the client did away with that, if that makes any sense.